# Escaping % symbol in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have a simple search box but I am trying to avoid the result page returning all results in table when the query is %. how can that be done?

Comment: Are you allowing any type of wildcard search? Or is what the user enters literally what you search for?

Comment: only what users enters and only using LIKE when searching titles of articles

Comment: Do you want % to still be a wildcard meaning "anything"? If so, then you should put a limit on your query, using the LIMIT clause (add i.e. `LIMIT 10` to the end of your query).

Comment: Then edit your question. It clearly states escaping the character, not removing it.

Comment: A `LIMIT` clause is probably still a good idea, in case the user searches for something extremely common (such as the letter 'a').

Comment: @stevether - To be fair, my answer is not a way to "escape" the % character, but rather to keep its special effects manageable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use `\%`...

In your PHP,

```
$query = str_replace ( '%' , '\%' , $query )

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($query) . "%'"
```

Comment: hmmm so how to check for it? like if($query == "\%") ?

Comment: you can do a string replace on it.

Comment: btw what you gave replaces the string...but how can I check if it is so I would like to redirect to another page...I tried if($query == "%") but not working

Comment: that would be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sanitizing your inputs?

You can start with [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($input) . "'";
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid mysql query on such a string on the first place.

Comment: Though real_escape_string is still needed, to protect against such things as single quotes.

Comment: Yes i did use it my friend :)